# Ask user for specified amount of characters?

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and I want to prompt the user to enter 10 characters exactly, anything more will just be ignored for example:

- Please enter 10 characters:

123412341234

- You entered: 1234123412

//and the 34 will be ignored because they entered more than 10

I got to here now:

```
string userInput;

    cout << "Please enter 10 characters!\n";
    cin >> userInput;

    cout << "You entered: "<< userInput << endl;
```

Thank you everyone. Hope I am as accurate as I can be.

Comment: Let the user enter anything they want, and have your program chop off any excess characters.

Comment: Mabe look at `Char16.size()` and `Char16.resize()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ask the user to enter a string and then take the substring of that

```
std::string userInput;

std::cout << "Please enter 10 characters: ";
std::cin >> userInput;

if(userInput.length() > 10)
{
    userInput = userInput.substr(0, 10);
}

std::cout << "You entered: " << userInput << std::endl;
```